# IIS Having trouble mapping correctly from .htaccess generated script

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite

I have just recently installed the URL rewriting tool for IIS7.5 & used the module to generate IIS specific rules for the .htaccess:

```
# Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php  [L]
```

Now, What I was trying to do. was route everything through index.php whilst removing the `.php` extension from the URL. I have this working on a local xampp development machine. Migrating over to the Windows Server 2008 IIS drived web server is causing problems for URLs mapping correctly. Could anyone provide assistance?

---

As requested:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!--# Options +FollowSymLinks  -->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is a module for [the webserver Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/). `.htaccess` is a configuration file for Apache. IIS is [a webserver made by Microsoft](http://www.iis.net/). Those are completely different things. Expecting that your rewriterules for Apache work on IIS is like expecting that copying the configuration files from Windows over to Linux will do anything sensible.

You'll need to recreate the rewriterules again on your IIS host (or use Apache instead). There is [a tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) on iis.net that teaches you how to create rewriterules on IIS. It will create an xml-formatted file `Web.config` in your www-root.

Comment: Yes. I installed & activated the URL Rewrite Module in IIS, imported the exact contents of `.htacccess` which is what is above. It does not work how it should. I tries to access `/SubDir/Dashboard/` for example, where `/Dashboard` should route through index.php so it can be processed.

Comment: Apache is not IIS. Your Apache configuration file will not work in IIS. That IIS has a url rewriting module as well doesn't change that. You'll have to configure your IIS url rewrite module differently, and the link in my answer tells you how. Click it. Read it. Please. I don't like to tell the exact same thing twice.

Comment: After re-reading that comment, I think you *might* have converted this rule into a rule in your IIS configuration, but for anyone to spot the problem, you'll have to edit your question and add your IIS rewrite config file.

Comment: If index.php isn't loaded at all, try removing `./` from the rewritten url. `./index.php` and `index.php` should be the same, but I am not sure how IIS responds to it. I notice you are rewriting to index.php without 'keeping' the url somehow. In Apache you can still get the original url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but this is not the case in IIS. If that might be the problem [click here](http://davidwalsh.name/iis-php-server-request_uri).